# Google API ClusterManager custom items rendering

Tags: java, android, google-maps

`enter code here`I need to display the cluster for the markers on the Google Map. 
I have custom object:

```
public class PostClusterItem implements ClusterItem {

private final LatLng mPosition;
BitmapDescriptor icon;
String title;
String desc;
}
```

Which I want to pass to the ClusterManager. 
I receive the set of the objects from the server and parse them all in the callback:

```
 @Override
public void onAllPostsLoaded(List<Post> postList) {
    mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<PostClusterItem>(getActivity(), googleMap);
    mClusterManager.clearItems();
    googleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(mClusterManager);
    googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);
    for (Post post : postList) {
        addMarkers(post);
    }
    mClusterManager.setRenderer(new CustomClusterRenderer(getActivity(), googleMap, mClusterManager));
}
```

my `addMarkers` method:

```
  private void addMarkers(Post post) {
    PostClusterItem postClusterItem = new PostClusterItem(post.getLat(), post.getLng(), post.getTitle(), post.getDescription());
    mClusterManager.addItem(postClusterItem);

}
```

But I don't know the reason, the clusterManager works badly: 
[image]

Markers do not properly added to the cluster, I can get and the next situation: 
[image]

But this situation does not exist, when I test on some simple object:

```
public class MyItem implements ClusterItem {
    private final LatLng mPosition;

    public MyItem(double lat, double lng) {
        mPosition = new LatLng(lat, lng);
    }
}
```

What can be reason of this?

Here is my `CustomClusterRenderer`

```
public class CustomClusterRenderer extends DefaultClusterRenderer<PostClusterItem> {

    public CustomClusterRenderer(Context context, GoogleMap map,
                       ClusterManager<PostClusterItem> clusterManager) {
        super(context, map, clusterManager);
    }


        protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered(PostClusterItem item, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
            super.onBeforeClusterItemRendered(item, markerOptions);
            markerOptions.snippet(item.getDesc());
            markerOptions.title(item.getTitle());

        }
    }
```

Comment: And what about your `CustomClusterRenderer` class? Can you test with `DefaultClusterRenderer`?

Comment: Actually clustering requires atleast five markers in nearby location to display them as a cluster

Comment: yes, exactly five. but as you can see from the 1st image - that is no 5 in the center of the circle.

Comment: yes, it works better with the DefaultClusterRenderer

Comment: @RikkiTikkiTavi so, post the code of `CustomClusterRenderer` for more help ;)

Comment: @Kevinrob already added in my question

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's too late but always call

```
mClusterManager.cluster();
```

after you add items.

This is a source code for ClusterManager here:
https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/clustering/ClusterManager.java

Here is some explanation:

```
/**
 * Force a re-cluster. You may want to call this after adding new item(s).
 */
public void cluster() {
...
```